# How to evaluate $ \int _{|z|=2} \frac{z dz}{(z^2-9)(z+i)}? $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I came across this question and I'm struggling with it. Could you try to help me me?

$ \int _{|z|=2}  \frac{z dz}{(z^2-9)(z+i)} $

I know that the answer is $ \frac{-\pi}{5}$

I was trying to use the Cauchy's integral formula

Comment: Where'd you get stuck when you were "trying to use the Cauchy's integral formula"?  Could you include the work you've done when "trying" within your post.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea to use the Cauchy integral formula is a good one.

It says that
$$\int_{|x|=2} \frac{\frac{z}{z^2-9}}{z+i} dz = 2\pi if(-i)$$
where 
$$f(z)=\frac{z}{z^2-9}.$$

Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{|z|=2} dz \frac{z/(z^2-9)}{z+i}=2\pi i \frac{z}{z^2-9}|_{z=-i}$

Comment: A few words never hurts, and this case, can only help.

Answer (score 0):

Your path of integration is $2e^{i\theta}$ We see that only $-i$ is contained within the contour, so using Cauchy's Formula $$f^n(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$$ your answer becomes $$2\pi i \frac{z}{z^2+9}|_{z=-i}=-\frac{\pi}{5}$$